# Javascript onload isn't working ("Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'document.body' of null ")

Tags: javascript, null, onload

Here is my codes:

Javascript:

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    function UP() {//Ẩn hiện nút UP
        if(window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight)
            document.getElementById('UP').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

HTML tag:

```
<button id="UP" onclick="toTop(350);"></button>
```

CSS style:

```
#UP {display: none;}
```

My idea is when I scroll down, then UP button will appear. But don't know why, it won't, it even return the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'document.body' of null". Of couse, I did change other script like this:

```
function getReady() {
    UP();
}
function UP() {//Ẩn hiện nút UP
    if(window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight)
        document.getElementById('UP').style.display = "block";
}
```

HTML tag:

```
<body onload="getReady();">
    <button id="UP" onclick="toTop(350);"></button>
</body>
```

It is even more terrible. When I load site, I didn't see onload attr of body tag and the browser didn't return any error for me.

Some other infomation:
I develop on both side, Cr & FF, it all says a same problem.
And I'm working on Wordpress source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify @laruiss and explain what is going on, lets start with your code:

```
/* body.onload is not recommended, window.onload is. But thats not the main issue*/
window.onload = function() {
    /* You are declaring a function here. Very important: 
     * its a declaration, NOT a function call 
     */
    function UP() {
        if(window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight)
            document.getElementById('UP').style.display = "block";
    }
    /* So if you want to execute ('call') your function, you have two options:
     * - Remove the declaration around your function aka `function UP(){` and the ending `}`
     * - Call the function here. To make your code work instantly, lets do that.
     */
    UP();
}
```

When using the onload event, you are actually doing the right thing. True, it's not *recommended* to actually do that in your DOM, but it should work. The biggest issue that DOM load is subjective. Some browsers will consider the body loaded as soon as the content is in, others will wait for images, and older IE versions won't fire it all! So if you use the recommended `window.onload`, you should be fine, as it will fire *as soon as the DOM is ready*. There is another great event for this you might want to consider, which is `DOMContentLoaded`, but its not as widely supported. Theres a bit more (by clicking through as well) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

I would also like to add that even though you put your button to display, its has no content so it could appear either empty or if you are resetting your button styles, not at all. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: It works like miracle. Thank you all of you. I will choose the answer of you 'cause even the fool English like me could understand then I think everyone could understand it well.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your code:

- `document.body.onload` should be replaced by `window.onload`, as said in the comments
- in the onload function, you define a function, but you don't invoke it...

So

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    function UP() {//Ẩn hiện nút UP
        if(window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight)
            document.getElementById('UP').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Should be replaced by:

```
window.onload = function up() { // Could be anonymous, of course, but should not
    if(window.pageYOffset > window.innerHeight)
        document.getElementById('UP').style.display = "block";
}
```

- last but not least, [you should not use the `on<Events>` HTML attributes](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Uhm, it does not have to be a defined function. Actually, it should be `window.onload = up;` **or** `window.onload = function(){}`, either anonimous **or** defined, but not using `window.onload` as a function definition as it won't be invoked...

Comment: @somethinghere I am not sure what you are saying, but in deed, I forgot to change `document.body` to `window`. I Edited my answer to change it.

Comment: What Im saying is that defining the event requires you to either pass it a named function or pass it an anonymous function, but not a 'named anonymous function'. (aka calling `window.event = function(){}` or doing `function doEvent(){}; window.event = doEvent;` both work. Doing `window.event = function doEvent(){}` is not good practise if it works, and it shouldn't work because you are technically naming the function twice. You will never be able to call `doEvent` after that anyway...) Also, you dont need to invoke the function, as the browser automatically invokes `window.onload`

Comment: Yes, much better explained... Though I disagree ;-) First I don't think it is bad practice, but there I could be wrong. Second, I am not naming the function twice, rather naming the function `"UP"` and assigning the function (which has a `name` property whose value is now `"UP"`) to the `window` property named `"onload"`, which is quite different. And therefore third: it works, and I don't see why it should not.

Comment: The thing is, there is no need to name the function as you have declared it as `window.onload`. You can call it by invoking `window.onload()`. You can't invoke the function later in your script by calling `UP()`, so its a bit useless. I posted a little more in my own answer, but essentially you have the right idea, so +1 for you!

Comment: You say "there is no need to name the function", no need to make it work, no, but it is better for debugging to name all the functions (event though the newer and to come JS engines will guess the function names for anonymous functions), and you could choose to call the function recursively within the `UP` function (which I should have renamed `up` in lowercase, BTW... there, done). But your answer is a correct answer, of course (even though more versbose ;-)). Nice chatting with you.

Comment: I'm quite the talker, yeah. I hadn't thought about recursive (although you _could_ use window.onload() to call recursive as what I meant is that you are doing `window.onload = up = function(){}`, but yeah it a good idea in that case!). Nice chatting too!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "My idea is when I scroll down, then UP button will appear." i think you should register '**scroll**' event on your scrollable container div. 'body/window.onload' function will be fired just once and hence it will not fullfill the requirement. Here is how you can proceed ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amitesh_Bharat/kLg3o38L/))

```
<div id="container" onscroll="handleScroll(this)">
    <button id="UP" onclick="toTop(350);">Go to Top</button>
     Scroll me</br>....scrollable content
```

Javascript

```
function handleScroll (obj) {
    var displayVal = "block";
    if (obj.scrollTop == "0") {
        displayVal = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById('UP').style.display = displayVal;
};
```